# python is returning an empty data frame

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

somewhat new to python and pandas specifically. I'm trying to run a query (connected through my company's db) to pull information in, setting parameters with the store_id and then outputting to csv. I know this sql returns data but for some reason, it's returning an empty data frame.

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
import pandas.io.sql as psql
from datetime import datetime
from sql_connect import connect_to_sql, connect_to_analytics #imports credentials and connects you to DB

con = connect_to_analytics()    

print "store id"
store = raw_input() 

#pull sales metrics by rule

sql = """SELECT day_date, rule.name, analytics.a.sku, pca.att_value as 'Category', sum(analytics.a.revenue) as 'revenue', sum(analytics.a.sales) as 'quantity', MAX(analytics.a.price) as 'price', sum(analytics.a.profit) as 'profit', SUM(analytics.a.profit)/SUM(analytics.a.revenue) AS 'margin', sum(analytics.a.hits) as 'total hits', sum(pps.in_stock) as 'inventory', sum(analytics.a.sales)/(sum(pps.in_stock) + sum(analytics.a.sales)) as 'sell thru'
FROM analytics.analytics_daily_skus_data as a
JOIN wp_data_prod.products_per_store as pps on analytics.a.store_id = pps.store_id AND analytics.a.sku = pps.sku
JOIN wp_data_prod.user_rule as rule ON pps.category_id = rule.id
JOIN wp_data_prod.pps_custom_attributes as pca on pps.id = pca.pps_id
WHERE pps.store_id =%s
AND analytics.a.day_date BETWEEN '2015-07-01'AND '2015-07-30'
AND pca.att_name = "str_category"
GROUP BY analytics.a.sku, day_date
ORDER BY analytics.a.sku, day_date""" 

df = pd.read_sql(sql % store, con=con)
print df
```

this is the output:

```
In [33]: print df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [day_date, name, sku, Category, revenue, quantity, price, profit, margin, total hits, inventory, sell thru]
Index: []
```

solution (figured it out today):

```
sql = """SELECT day_date, rule.name, analytics.a.sku, pca.att_value as 'Category', sum(analytics.a.revenue) as 'revenue', sum(analytics.a.sales) as 'quantity', MAX(analytics.a.price) as 'price', sum(analytics.a.profit) as 'profit', SUM(analytics.a.profit)/SUM(analytics.a.revenue) AS 'margin', sum(analytics.a.hits) as 'total hits', sum(pps.in_stock) as 'inventory', sum(analytics.a.sales)/(sum(pps.in_stock) + sum(analytics.a.sales)) as 'sell thru'
FROM analytics.analytics_daily_skus_data as a
JOIN wp_data_prod.products_per_store as pps on analytics.a.store_id = pps.store_id AND analytics.a.sku = pps.sku
JOIN wp_data_prod.user_rule as rule ON pps.category_id = rule.id
JOIN wp_data_prod.pps_custom_attributes as pca on pps.id = pca.pps_id
WHERE pps.store_id =('%s')
AND analytics.a.day_date BETWEEN '2015-07-01'AND '2015-07-30'
AND pca.att_name = "str_category"
GROUP BY analytics.a.sku, day_date
ORDER BY analytics.a.sku, day_date""" % (store)
```

Comment: Is store_id stored as string?

Comment: What happens if you try a simpler query? (eg. `SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 10`)

Comment: @CTZhu  yes, store ID is string

Comment: try print sql % store, and copy that into your SQL Gui tool, maybe something's going wrong with the variable substitution ... maybe it is a varchar, and needs to be in single quotes?

Comment: wouldn't you need `WHERE pps.store_id ="%s"`?

Comment: @maxymoo checked that and it's stored correctly

Comment: @CTZhu it's in the code above but without quotations around %s. Why would you need quotations around that?

Comment: don't know your schema, that variable could have been a varchar

Comment: what about this `pca.att_name = "str_category"`: try with single quotes? in many versions of SQL, double quotes are only for column names

Comment: @maxymoo store_id is stored as interger. Even if I flip between int(store_id) or str(store_id) I still get columns but an empty dataframe

Comment: Can you do `con.execute(sql % store).fetchall()` to see if the query actually returns data?

Comment: @joris - figured it out: pps.store_id = ('%s') then add % (store) after the """